# CIBlendWithAlphaMask only part of an image

Tags: ios, cocoa

**So I'm using `coregraphics` to apply masks between two different images - works perfectly when the images are the same size. **

```
    var scaleFilter = new CILanczosScaleTransform
    {
        InputImage = mask, 
        Scale = _firstImage.CGImage.Width / mask.Width
    };
    var filter = new CIBlendWithMask
    {
        InputImage = _firstImage.CGImage,
        BackgroundImage = _secondImage.CGImage,
        MaskImage = scaleMask.OutputImage
    };
    return filter.RenderAsUIImage();
```

However, what I'm trying to do is have the second image in a soft circle in the bottom right corner of the first image - the above code works perfectly, but I just get the matching little bit of the second image shining through - I actually want to scale the image down so it exactly fits the circle, but don't really get how doing it - if I scale the image with another filter, then it seems to be positioned in the bottom left corner, so I see nothing.  I sort of need to do a scale and translate, but **I don't really understand how the "translate" could work in the world of `CIFilters`.**

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/ciimage/1438203-transformed ?

Comment: yeah - saw that but I guess I don't understand the coordinate systems - unless there's some idea of an image where it lives in space, if I use an affine transform to make it smaller it will just bounce back to the origin, right?

Comment: actually - ignore me - I tried it 
            affineTransform.Transform = new CGAffineTransform(0.5f, 0, 0, 0.5f, _firstImage.CGImage.Width/2, 0); - and it worked.   I'd looked at that and thought it wouldn't.   Thanks!